# Unity Android plugin (connecting Thalmic devices) doesn't work on 6.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow, myo

I have an Unity game which use an Android Plugin. This plugin is used for connecting and sending the informations from thalmic bracelets to my Unity Game.

In this plugin there is a scanner for detecting the bracelet using Bluetooth. The scanner works on Android 4 but when I try it on Android 6.0, the scanner doesn't detect anything.

I don't know if you guys know what could cause this, I'm a little lost right now.

Thank you

Comment: What Unity version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Unity 5.3.5

Comment: I put my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely permission problem. Things changed in Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Android permission is now asked during run-time.

This is a bug that is now fixed in Unity `5.4.0B15` to support **Marshmallow**.

**Unity 5.4.0B15 Android Marshmallow** - *Fixed issues when querying for custom permissions.*

Update to [5.4.0B15](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta) or above in order to fix this problem.

Comment: @kekout Ok. I  will be waiting to hear what happens

Comment: I've tried with Unity 5.4.0b23 and the scanner still doesn't detect the bracelets :/